# How to remove initial dot from a string in a variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable named myVar in bash with value as shown below.

```
'./favicon.png' './inc/sendEmail.php' './index.html' './images/header-background.jpg'
```

Note: the above code is the value of one variable

And I want want to change it to the below string by removing initial dot from each path

```
'/favicon.png' '/inc/sendEmail.php' '/index.html' '/images/header-background.jpg'
```

I am not able to figure out how to do this. Please help.

Comment: That's possible, for example using `sed "s/'\./'/g" <<< "$string"`, but if you have any control over whatever generates the string, you should fix it where it's created, and also use an array instead of a string with hardcoded quotes, as any further processing tends to be more difficult with what you have.

Comment: Is the dot in `xyz./abc` to be removed as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bash parameter expansion?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

myVar="'./favicon.png' './inc/sendEmail.php' './index.html' './images/header-background.jpg'"

echo "${myVar//.\///}"
```

```
'/favicon.png' '/inc/sendEmail.php' '/index.html' '/images/header-background.jpg'
```